# How to avoid FULL OUTER JOIN in sqldf in R

Tags: r, sqldf

I have two dataframes (let's assign `df1` and `df2`), each of them has 1347 columns (and colnames of both dataframes are absolutely identical) and different number of rows (730 in `df1` and 706 in `df2`).

I need to compute the difference between all columns (except one, i.e. difference between 1346 columns) and to save the names of columns. And the best way I knew is to compose the sql statement with `full outer join` connection in `sqldf` package because I need the full range of objects.
Here is the small example:

```
sqldf("select a.regn, a.col1 - b.col1 as col1, a.col2 - b.col2 as col2 ... 
       from df1 a full outer join df2 b on a.regn = b.regn")
```

However `sqldf` doesn't provide `full outer join`.

As soon as the number of columns are quite high I composed my SQL statement in loop.

How can I avoid this issue?

Comment: It does supoport it if you use the PostgreSQL backend.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck what do you mean?

Comment: It supports 4 backends. Read the docs.

Comment: I wonder if it would be quicker to rearrange your tables into long format. That might work in R, I'm not sure if also for a would work for a database...

Answer (score 0):

You could combine two `left outer joins` which are working in the `SQLite` backend:

```
sqldf("select a.regn, a.col1 - b.col1 as col1, a.col2 - b.col2 as col2 ... 
       from df1 a left outer join df2 b on a.regn = b.regn UNION
       select a.regn, a.col1 - b.col1 as col1, a.col2 - b.col2 as col2 ... 
       from df2 a left outer join df1 b on a.regn = b.regn 
")
```

This works provided you don't have duplicate rows in `df1` or `df2` because `UNION` removes duplicate rows.